# Join 2 tables on foreign key while using count() in SQL

Tags: sql

So I have two tables: [Please see the ER diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBpMZ.png)

I want to use SELECT to create one table with "name" from the USER table, "id" as the foreign key for the two tables, and the count of friend_id as the number of friends each user has.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT name, id, (SELECT count(friend_id) as number
    FROM friend
    GROUP BY user_id)
    FROM user
ORDER BY number DESC
```

I'm wondering what's the problem with these lines. Thank you!

Comment: Please add sample data for both tables to the question.

Comment: If you want this query format you need to make your sub-query *correlational*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to calculate the count.

```
SELECT name, id, COALESCE(f.Count, 0) AS friend_count
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT friend_id) AS Count
    FROM friend
    GROUP BY user_id
) f ON f.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY friend_count DESC
```

I used a `LEFT JOIN` so that if a user doesn't have a row in `friend`, it will still return a row with a friend count of 0 (thanks to `COALESCE`). I also added a `DISTINCT` so that if the friend has duplicates the friend is counted only one, might not be necessary especially if you have a `UNIQUE INDEX` setup on columns `user_id, friend_id`

Answer (score 0):

Just add `where` to find only one id and remove `group by` because you have only one id for one or more friends as your diagram says.

```sql
SELECT name, id, (SELECT count(friend_id) as number
    FROM friend
    WHERE user_id = user.id)
    FROM user
ORDER BY number DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be correct for you puprose

```
CREATE TABLE #user(
    id VARCHAR(22),
    [name] VARCHAR(255),
)

CREATE TABLE #friend(
    user_id VARCHAR(22),
    friend_id VARCHAR(22)
)


SELECT name, id, (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(friend_id), 0)
    FROM #friend f
    WHERE f.user_id = u.id
    GROUP BY user_id) as number
    FROM #user u
ORDER BY number DESC

--Same query with join:

SELECT u.[name], u.id, COALESCE(COUNT(f.friend_id),0) number
FROM #user u
LEFT JOIN #friend f ON f.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.[name], u.id
ORDER BY number
```